# Shifting same byte gives different values

Tags: java, byte

Code:

```
System.out.println((byte)0b10000000 >> 6);
System.out.println(0b10000000 >> 6);
```

Output:

```
-2
2
```

I know that passing in an uncasted byte will turn it into an Integer (second line).
It still gives the expected answer of `2`, aka 0b10.

However, casting it as an Byte (first line) returns `-2`.

I am confused why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bytes are 8 bit signed integers, so when you cast the first binary number to `byte`, the first bit is interpreted as the sign, therefore it's interpreted as `-127`.

You can solve this by using `System.out.println((byte)(0b10000000 >> 6));` (casting **after** the shift).

> I know that passing in an uncasted byte...

Erm, `0b...` does not mean "byte;" it means "binary." You are not passing in an uncasted byte at all. (Your binary literal does *fit* in a byte, but it's interpreted as an int.)

Answer (score 0):

[The shift operator `>>` keeps the sign bit.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19)

> The value of n >> s is n right-shifted s bit positions with sign-extension.

So the byte value

```
1000 0000
```

promoted to an `int`, [as required by the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19)

> Unary numeric promotion (§5.6.1) is performed on each operand separately.

gives

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1000 0000
```

because [widening conversion from `byte` to `int`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)

> A widening conversion of a signed integer value to an integral type T
>   simply sign-extends the two's-complement representation of the integer
>   value to fill the wider format.

and shifted by 6 becomes

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110
```

which is the integer value -2.

In the case of

```
System.out.println(0b10000000 >> 6);
```

The literal is actually an `int`, ie.

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000 0000
```

so shifting by 6 to the right becomes

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 000 0010
```

with a value of 2.

Comment: That's actually not true.  The byte value would be 11111110 which is -2.  Even the integer value would be 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110, but that's only from casting not from shifting.

Comment: @TedBigham What's not true? I missed what you were referring to.

Comment: Shifting a byte doesn't widen it to an int.  You can silently cast it into an int (because of widening), but it otherwise stays a byte.  The byte 11111110 is also -2 which is more accurately the result of shifting right 6 times.

Comment: @TedBigham In the first case, the literal `0b10000000` is an `int` with value `2`. When cast with `(byte)` it becomes the `byte` value `-128`. Unary numeric promotion occurs because `<<` requires it. That requires a widening numeric promotion of the `byte` to an `int`. This promotion uses sign extension. So, in whole, you go from `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000 0000` to `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1000 0000` before the shift occurs.

Comment: In the first case, the literal 0b10000000 is an int with value **128**.  Casting it to byte makes it negative.  Promotion doesn't actually occur (from any coding point of view) or else you'd have to cast the result to assign it back to a byte.  It might be an integer behind the scenes but that more about the JVM than the Java language.

Comment: @TedBigham Sorry I copied that value wrong. Yes, it is 128. The `(byte)` cast is used on the literal not on the result of `<<`. So the `int` literal value is cast to a `byte`. The shift operator **requires (the Java Language requires)** that unary numeric promotion happens. So the `byte` value of `-128` is promoted to the `int` value `-128`. And then _that_ value is used in the shift. If you take a look with your favorite IDE, you'll notice that the `println()` method used is the one that accepts an `int`.

Comment: that makes more sense. I thought you were saying casting a int 2 into a byte makes -128 and my head exploded.  FYI, PrintWriter doesn't have a println(byte), but your example works for handmade byte/int methods.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the steps of each shift to make it clear what's happening

byte (signed with MSB=1)

```
10000000(-128)
11000000(-64)
11100000(-32)
11110000(-16)
11111000(-8)
11111100(-4)
11111110(-2)
```

integer (signed with MSB=0)

```
0000000010000000(128)
0000000001000000(64)
0000000000100000(32)
0000000000010000(16)
0000000000001000(8)
0000000000000100(4)
0000000000000010(2)
```